# Kähler manifold with Ricci-flat Kähler form 

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds, fa.functional-analysis

hallo,

I have the following problem: Let $X$ be a $n-$dim Kähler manifold with Ricci-flat Kähler form $\omega$. There is a known fact that then there exists a holomorphic (n,0)-form $\Omega$ such that $\frac{\omega^{n}}{n!} = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(i/2)^{n} \Omega \wedge \bar{\Omega}$. And that $\Omega$ is also parallel with respect to the Levi-civita connection. 
Does anyone know where I can find a proof of this assertion? I would be very thankful for answers.

greetings
bruno

Answer (score 6):

You need some more hypotheses for the existence of the $(n,0)$-form, in general it will exist only up to finite torsion. For example, an Enriques surface does not admit a nowhere zero holomorphic $(2,0)$-form. You can also construct explicit examples with products of two or three elliptic curves quotiented by a group generated by well chosen involutions.

When such an $n$-form exists, the usual way to prove that it is parallel is to use a Bochner technique. This is sketched in the first pages of Beauville's ["Variétés Kahleriennes dont la premiere classe de Chern est nulle"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-18/issue-4/Vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s-K%C3%A4hleriennes-dont-la-premi%C3%A8re-classe-de-Chern-est-nulle/10.4310/jdg/1214438181.full) (the proof might work for the general case, i.e., for $(n,0)$-forms that have some zeros by using that the norm in the Bochner technique will not be zero at all points). If I recall correctly, a more complete version of the same argument is given in ["Calabi-Yau manifolds and their friends"](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDoQFjAD&url=http://carlossicoli.free.fr/G/Gross_M._Huybrechts_D.,_Joyce_D.-Calabi-Yau_Manifolds_and_Related_Geometries%282003%29.pdf&ei=MIFRUIKPOMi90QWs_YCgCA&usg=AFQjCNFXTtawQZcYLHXK0v4iHprjtN64tg&sig2=MKSGMfInjBlr221Yt1MUZw&cad=rja) and in the opening chapters of ["Mirror symmetry"](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/mirrorfinal.pdf&ei=rYFRUJK9M-qw0QX8oIGQDg&usg=AFQjCNFNtSEM20sKW-oD0BH4KOQHHSm6fA&sig2=UZ5hLCAvX08K6xDi7ODA-Q).

Comment: does one maybe need the assumption that $X$ is compact ?

Comment: Yes: if $\tau$ is a holomorphic $p$-form then the Bochner formula gives $\Delta \| \tau \|^2 = \| D \tau \|^2$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian and $D$ the connection, so the function $x \mapsto \|\tau(x) \|^2$ is subharmonic on the manifold. From there we need compactness to deduce it is constant and thus that $\tau$ is parallel.

Comment: and what about for the first assumption. is it enough to assume that $X$ is compact?

Comment: The tricky part in all this is getting a holomorphic form $\Omega$. If you have that, I think it is automatically parallel: a volume form $\omega^n/n!$ defines a smooth hermitian metric $h$ on the canonical bundle by $$h(\alpha,\beta) \omega^n/n! = i^{n^2} \alpha \wedge \overline \beta.$$ If $i^{n^2} \Omega \wedge \overline \Omega = \omega^n/n!$ then $\|\Omega\|_h^2 = 1$, so $\Omega$ is parallel by the Bochner formula. So if you have the form, it is parallel, but the manifold may not be compact (example: $\mathbb C$, $\Omega = dz$).